# Get table values in web site via using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, html-agility-pack

Hi I want to get IP address and PORT and the country names in this web site http://proxylist.hidemyass.com

I'm new in `HtmlAgilityPack` also I don't know Linq. May you help me to get that values? Thank you.

Comment: So either you're asking us to teach you both Linq and HtmlAgilityPack, in which case this question is too broad, or you're showing no effort and effectively asking someone else to do your work. Either way, it's a close vote from me. http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: No i already tried something but didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                string src = wc.DownloadString("http://proxylist.hidemyass.com");

                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hd = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                hd.LoadHtml(src);

                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode table = hd.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr[@class='#altshade']");

                bool First = false;
                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode trs in table.ChildNodes)//.Where(i => i.Name == "tr" && i.InnerText.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    if (First)
                    {
                        Proxy p = new Proxy();
                        foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode tds in trs.ChildNodes.Where(i => i.InnerText.Trim() != string.Empty))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(tds.InnerText);
                        }
                        Proxies.Add(p);
                    }
                    First = true;
                }
```